# What is fallacious about an argument that "I know X well, so she is right"?

Tags: logic, fallacies

I often hear from media personalities that they are right about a theory or assertion merely by associating themselves with someone or something.

For example:

- "I know Mr. X very well (for years) and i know that he wouldn't do something like that."
- "I've been in the X Organization for years. The X Organization would clearly do X, Y, Z"

What is this fallacy called? I tried reviewing the list of fallacies on the internet and couldn't figure it out.

Or is this not really categorized as a fallacy?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How is this different from argument from authority?  In this case, the person claims authority via long-term association.  But the falsehood is not that long-term association makes you familiar with something; the falsehood is that because you are an authority on X that you always know how X will act.

Comment: `because you are an authority on X that you *always know* how X will act.` "always know" seems to be the key here.

Answer (score 2):

I would go with [Fallacy of Composition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fallacy_of_composition).

> The fallacy of composition arises when one infers that something is
> true of the whole from the fact that it is true of some part of the
> whole (or even of every proper part). For example: "This fragment of
> metal cannot be broken with a hammer, therefore the machine of which
> it is a part cannot be broken with a hammer." This is clearly
> fallacious, because many machines can be broken into their constituent
> parts without any of those parts being breakable.
>
> This fallacy is often confused with the fallacy of hasty
> generalization, in which an unwarranted inference is made from a
> statement about a sample to a statement about the population from
> which it is drawn.

It is kind of the reverse of the norm because we are infering: because it is true of some part of the whole, it is true of the whole.  But it is still a compositional fallacy.